# Chrome developer tools from JavaScript

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to access meta information provided by Chrome developer tools in JavaScript on a page? For example the bounding rectangle of an element, if element under cursor etc.

Thx for answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this information is not available directly through JS. However you can use the [remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) (and the [Debugger API](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/debugger.html) is available as a transport in your extensions) to get that info.